# requestAnimationFrame inside a Promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, requestanimationframe

Can someone please explain what this function does? I understand how the `requestAnimationFrame` executes before the paint and render within a frame, but I'm not really sure what's the utility of putting it inside a promise.

```js
function nextFrame() {
  return new Promise(requestAnimationFrame)
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer gives a great explanation of the mechanics. I think one big motivation would be that you can write `await nextFrame();` inside an `async` function, e.g. at the top of a loop that should run once per animation step.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Constructor_Syntax) constructor accepts a so called `executor` function as it's first argument, which can be used to control promise execution flow. This function has two arguments: `resolve` and `reject` - these are functions you call to either resolve or reject a promise.

```
const promise = new Promise(function executor(resolve, reject) {
   resolve();
   // reject();
});
```

That `executor` function is called internally automatically when you create a new promise using `new Promise(executor)`.

Next, [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) requires a callback, which will be fired whenever a browser is ready to execute your frame code.

```
requestAnimationFrame(function frameCallback(timestamp) {
    // ...frame code
});
```

If you try to impose `requestAnimationFrame(frameCallback)` signature on top of `executor(resolve, reject)` signature, then

- `requestAnimationFrame` is `executor` function
- `frameCallback` is `resolve` function

To put it all together, using `new Promise(requestAnimationFrame)`

1. Promise constructor internally calls an executor (in this case
   `requestAnimationFrame`). As `requestAnimationFrame` is called,
   browser internally schedules it as a request for animation.
2. When browser is ready to animate requested frame, it invokes a callback provided to `requestAnimationFrame`. In our case `resolve` serves as a callback. In addition `resolve` will be passed with a timestamp from `requestAnimationFrame` i.e. the promise will be resolved with a timestamp value.

I guess this code can be used to Promise-ify `requestAnimationFrame`, contstructed promise will be resolved as soon as `requestAnimationFrame` callback is called.

```
const promise = new Promise(requestAnimationFrame);
promise.then(function frameCallback(timestamp) => {
  // ... frame code
});
```