# How to implement requestAnimationFrame loop with asynchronous callback?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, requestanimationframe

I found a couple of questions pretty close to what I am looking for, but either I don't understand enough or the questions/answers do not exactly apply to what I am looking for:

- [How to use requestAnimationFrame with Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65144038/how-to-use-requestanimationframe-with-promise)
- [requestAnimationFrame inside a Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61017477/requestanimationframe-inside-a-promise)

Consider a very simple example of a requestAnimationFrame loop:

```
const someList = [];

function main() {
    // Start the requestAnimationFrame loop
    requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

function update() {
    doSomething()

    // Loop by calling update again with requestAnimationFrame
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function doSomething() {
    someList.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
}

main();
```

Now here we do not have any problems. We start the loop, do something within the loop, call requestAnimationFrame again and everything is fine.

Now consider this next example. Here we have an async function called `doSomethingAsynchronous` and it has to be called with `await`. Therefore our `update` function needs to be `async` as well. My problem is that I do not understand how to work with `requestAnimationFrame` when the callback-function passed to the `requestAnimationFrame` is asynchronous:

```
function main() {
    // Since update must now be async as well and called with await, what should this line look like?
    requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

function async update() {
    await doSomethingAsynchronous()

    // Since update must now be async as well and called with await, what should this line look like?
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function async doSomethingAsynchronous() {
    // Can't come up with an example, but this function should be called with await
}

main();
```

I feel like the requestAnimationFrame line in the code should probably look like one of these:

```
await requestAnimationFrame(update)
await requestAnimationFrame(async () => { await update(); });
requestAnimationFrame(async () => { await update(); });
```

But I'm not exactly sure if `requestAnimationFrame` can or should be awaited. In case I need to supply the `update` callback as an `async` function, that is also something I can't wrap my head around.

**Edit:**

In case someone is wondering why I am using `requestAnimationFrame`, the reason is that I am using TensorflowJS Object Detection model which returns the detection results asynchronously. So I want to asynchronously get the results and then render and visualize the results of a canvas - thus the `requestAnimationFrame`.

**Edit 2:**

As it has become apparent to me that this issue might not have a very generic solution, but instead the answer depends on the specific use case by a great deal, I'll add further additional information.

The issue is as follows:

- There is a video feed
- We pull each frame of the video as it plays and feed the frames to a TensorflowJS Object Detection Model
- The model's `predict` function is asynchronous and it returns bounding boxes for the objects it detects in the video frame
- We want to draw the video feed on a canvas and we also want to draw these bounding boxes on top when we get them from the model

My idea is to do all of this in a `requestAnimationFrame` loop. The reason why I need to perform an asynchronous function call within this loop is because the Object Detection Model's `predict` function is asynchronous.

So to put it simply:

```
Video -> 
Pull frame -> 
(*) Draw the frame on canvas ->
Asynchronously run Object Detection on the frame ->
Draw the Bounding Boxes returned by the Object Detection Model on the canvas (->)
(*) Draw the frame on canvas
```

(*) Preferably we should draw the video frame on canvas as soon as possible, before running the Object Detection, but I think it would be fine to do it after in case it is easier and/or less of a hassle. Either way we obviously do NOT want to draw the video frame twice, but instead only once at either point in time.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame()` does not understand async functions. In general, it does not care about the return value from any function passed as a callback.

Comment: Why are you using rAF? The fact you have an async function running there is a red herring. By the time your async task will return, the browser will already have updated its rendering, so if you do await the result of an async call to render something (basically what rAF is supposed to be used for), you'll actually miss the rendering.

Comment: @Kaiido Ahh I didn't realize I should have mentioned that I am indeed rendering stuff, thus the rAF. I am actually using Tensorflow and I get the image detection results from an async function and I then want to visualize the results on a canvas so I am using rAF loop for the rendering. Do share if you have a nice solution or idea for something like this.

Comment: Again, why would you still use rAF? As your function is async, chances are that more than just one paint cycle has already passed, and so you can execute your rendering code immediately after your async function's promise has resolved, without rAF. Please clarify why you think rAF is still needed?

Comment: @Swiffy I think you just should not use `requestAnimationFrame` at all. What's wrong with waiting for the image detection results and then immediately paint them to the canvas once they're available? Are you actually doing any sort of animation?

Comment: @trincot I'm beginning to think that my understanding of rAF might be incorrect. My understanding of rAF and the "loop-form" of it specifically has been that it can be used to essentially easily render something as fast as the monitor/hardware allows and with a non-fixed framerate. Additionally rAF seems to not block the event loop in the same way a simple while-loop would. I've regarded rAF as the more performant, dynamic and gold standard solution to achieve more "advanced rendering" instead of just using a loop or setInterval.

Comment: rAF is used to not have your code make updates faster than the frame rate, and to only consume processing time when the system is ready to perform a paint cycle. But when you have an asynchronous task that must finish first, then you're likely to be *slower* with your next rendering code than the frame-rate allows. So then rAF has no real benefit anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` (rAF) will queue your callback to be called right before the browser updates its rendering. This means that any new task¹ queued from such a callback will get executed only **after** the browser did update the rendering.

So having an *async* function inside an rAF callback is a sign of something potentially bad in your code design. If you did expect whatever data received asynchronously from that function to be rendered, it won't be in that frame. Worst, if you do prepare your rendering in different timings you may have half-baked frames, or even nothing at all, e.g if you clear a `<canvas>` in the synchronous part of your *async* function and then render whatever the data you received in the async function, at the time the browser renders, the `<canvas>` would be blank, and the painted frame would be cleared by the next frame call:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const checkbox = document.querySelector("input");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const getColor = async () => {
  if (checkbox.checked) {
    await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 0));
  }
  return "green";
}

const asyncRenderer = async () => {
  // prepare the context for rendering
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  const color = await getColor();
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  // won't be visible
  ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 50, 50);
}

const loop = async () => {
  while (true) { 
    await new Promise((res) => requestAnimationFrame(res));
    await asyncRenderer();
  }
};

loop();
```

```html
<label>await in getColor<input type=checkbox checked></label>
<canvas></canvas>
```

---

Instead, you'll probably want to separate the updating phase of your animation and the rendering one.

How you do this will vary on the actual setup. Some may want to produce enough data as fast as possible so that they can buffer a few frames and be sure to be able to render every frames (e.g. in cases the data is generated from complex calculations in a Web Worker) and only produce more frames when reaching a threshold. Here the rendering loop could only trigger the data generator once in a while.

Some may prefer to require the data only when needed, e.g. if it comes from the network. In such a case, using rAF as a throttler is actually fine. You just have to be conscious that the data you request in rAF will be rendered one frame later, and that you may have some frames with no rendering.

And in your case, it seems that you're in a hybrid situation, where the data gathering is actually dependent on some external factor like the frequency at which new images are available to generate the object recognition on.
You don't say where your TensorFlow instance receives its input images from, but if we assume it's a video stream, then you will want to throttle the processing to both the stream frequency and the monitor frame-rate.

Assuming you gather the TensorFlow input from a `<video>` element, then you may want to have a look at [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699721/javascript-extract-video-frames-reliably/32708998#32708998) where I describe various methods to extract every frames of a video, or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68402476/event-for-every-frame-of-html-video/68402944#68402944) where I explain how to get an event at each frame of a `<video>` element. Spoiler alert, it's not easy to get a cross-browser solution.
Once you have this running you'll need a more complex setup where you'll have one loop that awaits both that input event and rAF to gather new data, and another loop to render the new data when available, at the monitor's refresh rate.

```js
// A simple helper
const waitForRAF = async () => {
  return new Promise((res) => requestAnimationFrame(res));
}
const requestDataFromTensor = async () => {
  // Send new data to the worker, wait for its response.
};
const waitForVideoInput = async () => {
  // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699721
}
let data = null; // We'll store the Tensor results in here
const updateDataFromTensorFlow = async () => {
  await waitForVideoInput();
  data = await requestDataFromTensor();
};
const updateLoop = async () => {
  while (true) {
    // Wait for both the data update and rAF,
    // so we don't produce useless data in case
    // it takes less than a monitor frame.
    await Promise.all([
      updateDataFromTensorFlow(),
      waitForRAF(),
    ]);
  }
}
const draw = (dataFromTensor) => {
  // Actually draw on your <canvas>
}
const renderLoop = async () => {
  while (true) {
    await waitForRAF();
    if (data) {
      draw(data);
      data = null; // Avoid redrawing if nothing new was received since last frame
    }
  }
}
// Now run both loops in parallel
updateLoop();
renderLoop();
```

---

*Footnotes:*
<sub>1. Also colloquially called "macrotask". Microtasks queued from an rAF callback will still execute before the next render, so having an *async* function in an rAF callback might work, if you ensure that the awaited data is actually already available, e.g. `await Promise.race([getDataMaybeAlreadyThere(), Promise.resolve()])`, but that is still a code-smell.</sub>

Comment: Amazing. I am extremely thankful for the incredible effort you've put in your answer. Again, I will have to say that I'm sorry that I didn't originally understand how much my specific use case mattered with regards to this. Instead, I assumed that my issue would be more generic. I am going to implement your proposition on Monday and see how it goes, but by the looks of it, it is looking VERY promising! I'm also very grateful for the VideoDecoder examples you linked; I've fiddled with MediaStreams and VideoDecoders before to the point that I was diving deep inside the W3C specs and it was tough

Comment: Furthermore your assumption is correct. I am feeding the video frames to the Tensorflow Model; so far I've accomplished this by simply drawing each frame on a canvas and pulling the image data from there. I was aware that this was far from the optimal solution and it was my intention to optimize this at some point, but I hadn't exactly given a lot of thought as to how exactly I would be doing that. Thanks for supplying me with an expanded and specific answer to my use case. Eventhough we have all these new Media etc. APIs, it is still not exactly easy to do certain things like you said.

Comment: Do you reckon that I should edit the question title itself to better reflect the specific use case? I already edited the question itself with some additional information, now that it has become clear to me that the issue isn't very generic.

Comment: No I think it's fine, even for the global case this might be useful. I tried to give general advice in my answer to that effect. Generally, having an async callback inside rAF is a code-smell.

Comment: Following up: I've marked this as answered. I tested this answer as well, but with my actual implementation I am actually going with the answer you've linked. The combination of `requestVideoFrameCallback` and `createImageBitmap` as described in the linked answer works like a charm and it is surprisingly fast too!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with the code you propose yourself, but as you have not included the *rendering* code, make sure that it is executed at the *top* of your `update` function, so that once `update` is called, it is executed synchronously.

I would however suggest to *promisify* `requestAnimationFrame` like this:

```
const nextFrame = () => new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve));
```

And then you can write an async `while` loop where you await both your own promise and the `nextFrame` one:

```js
const nextFrame = () => new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(resolve));

async function main() {
    let counter = 0;
    while (true) { // An async loop
        // Rendering code comes here: some simple counter example
        //      ....
        document.querySelector("div").textContent = counter++;
        //
        // After rendering code, immediately call the async function
        await doSomething();
        // If you really want to, await the start of the next paint cycle
        await nextFrame();
    }
}

// Dummy implementation:
const doSomething = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));

main();
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Wrapping in an arrow function is actually "better": If one day requestAnimationFrame is updated to accept a second parameter, then it will receive the Promise constructor's second argument (the rejector), which may break things. In that exact case it's probably fine because a lot of websites actually do this and thus we can't change rAF signature anymore, but please don't advocate for it.

Comment: *"thus we can't change rAF signature anymore"*: I get your point, but that is not entirely true. The addition of a parameter to rAF would only pose a problem if it was a *callback* parameter, *and* it could be called before the first callback was called. This is never going to happen. For instance, it really is no problem if an options parameter would be added of some sort, like `addEventListener` has.

Comment: What if that option bag was looking at a `.name` property, or a `.length` one?

Comment: I can't see why such properties would be used, but even if so, I have removed the short variant from my answer.

Comment: One case that may already have come up and got rejected because of that Promise thing IIRC is for debugging, just like [Worker's one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker#name), but one could imagine it used to point to an [AnimationTimeline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnimationTimeline), or a to be defined Compositor or whatever. `length` could be used to tell how many frames it should wait before firing, (e.g. if you want to render only once every *x* frames), or for other purposes I don't think of right now. The point being, better not assume.

Comment: `length` would be a really, really bad name for that.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't matter, we don't know what other properties will be added to `Function` in the future, and we don't know what option names would be useful to such an option bag, so we can't set a new param to `requestAnimationFrame` because too many websites use that shortcut already and there is a  real risk of breaking them. But that doesn't mean I don't do such thing as  `filter(Boolean)` when I'm lazy myself. Just, we should not advocate for that practice.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make async rendering:

```js
let running = true;
async function update(cb) {
  while(running){
    const renderCb = await cb();
    requestAnimationFrame(renderCb);
  }
}
let counter = 0;
async function doSomething() {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100));
    return ()=>$div.textContent = counter++;
}

update(doSomething)
```

```html
<div id="$div"></div>
<button onclick="running=false">Stop</button>
```

Comment: That is interesting. It looks like you have sort of decoupled requestAnimationFrame from the callback loop itself. I'll test this out soon!

Comment: @Swiffy yes, it's more manageable, looks better also

Comment: @Swiffy added a solution to call the callback with `requestAnimationFrame`

Comment: Why would they want rAF first? They certainly don't want it there actually. If they do so they will definitely have the async result too late, and may even render half baked frame if some of the rendering is done before the async data is returned.

Comment: @Kaiido the render should happen sync, as with the original solution when the callback is called by rAF, otherwise another solution should be provided like the callback returns a callback for rendering or something else

Comment: Yes that's my point. Having an async function in rAF means they'll not render sync.

Comment: @Kaiido the OP doesn't render anything btw

Comment: @Kaiido added an async rendering

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I replied to Kaiido in the comment section of my question regarding why I am using rAF, in case that makes a difference. Sorry for that, I didn't realize it was important to add!

Comment: @Swiffy then use the last solution, i've tweaked it and removed the first ones

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Is there any way to keep the rAF inside the update function? Feels weird to have it inside doSomething, especially if I happen to have various async doSomething functions.

Comment: @Swiffy yes, returned the previous variant